# gyro for turtlebot

Tags: ros, gyro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm looking for a gyro for my turtlbot, but the ones that I've found the [drivers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/imu_drivers) are horribly expensive (microstan -> £1592+VAT!). Now I am looking for a normal gyro (arround £50-70), but my question is: will I have to build the drivers or the drivers for the gyro that turtlebot uses by default with iCreate (SparkFun ADXRS613S/623 Breakout Board) will more or less work with any gyro??

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12745/gyro-for-turtlebot/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short, yes you should be able to get away with replacing your turtlebot's gyro with another similar one without having to "write a driver" per se--since most cheap gyros operate in the same manner: outputting an analog voltage proportional to the angular rate about the axis of the sensor package it should only require minor modification of the turtlebot's existing gyro.py python module.

A post on how to hook up a rate gyro mimicking the configuration in the turtlebot (its not specific to the ADXRS613 it refers to) can be found [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/717/is-an-imu-required-to-run-turtlebot-stack#1243). This can be useful if you don't actually have a turtlebot, but rather just a create with a laptop (no turtlebot power/gyro board).

Unfortunately the main distributor for the [ADXRS613 breakout](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9059) was Sparkfun and they've discontinued that breakout due to the chip being end-of-lifed by the manufacturer.  You may be able to find some resellers that still have stock, but I haven't had much success.

**UPDATE**: There seem to be a few left [here](http://www.active-robots.com/sensors/gyros/gyro-breakout-board-adxrs613.html), however these will probably dry up soon.

**UPDATE 2**: It should be noted that ClearPath, one of the distributors of the Turtlebot has apparently [switched to the ADXRS652 chip](http://answers.ros.org/question/2122/gyro-substitute-for-turtlebot?answer=3550#3550). Since they have in-house fab capability, its unlikely they'll produce a breakout for this chip--you'd have to make your own or wait for someone like Sparkfun to make one.

The MLX90609 breakout might make a suitable replacement (from [Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8371) or [Active Robots](http://www.active-robots.com/sensors/gyros/gyro-breakout-board-mlx90609-e2.html)).  Again, if you're just operating with a iRobot Create then you can hook up the analog out of the gyro to the same DB-25 pins described in the first linked post.  You may still have to modify
[gyro.py](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/70f12313a782/turtlebot_node/src/turtlebot_node/gyro.py) in the src folder of the turtlebot_node package a bit.  Taking a quick glance at that file shows a slightly different formula for calculating orientation than I'm familiar with, so here's the calculation (in C++) that I use on my cheap gyro (from [bilibot repo](http://code.google.com/p/bilibot-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/bilibot/bilibot_node/src/node.cpp)):

```
    double dt = current_time - last_time; // last time we read ADC
    double maxValue = 1024; // using Create's 10-bit ADC
    double vRef = 5;  // 5v reference
    double zeroRateV = avg * vRef / maxValue; // I calculate zeroRateV from a circular buffer during startup, avg is the average of these values
    double sensitivity = 0.013;  // mV/deg/sec from datasheet

    rate = (gyro_adc * vRef / maxValue - zeroRateV) / sensitivity;

    orientation += rate * dt;
```

You'll have to figure out from the datasheet what the sensitivity (mV/deg/sec) value is and substitute it in the equation above.  It should be relatively trivial to modify gyro.py's publish method if need be to match the above calculation.

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3